# I loose my normals when I export as a fbx. I keep the rest of my textures

Tags: normals, .fbx

So for some of reason when I export my model as a fbx it only exports half the textures

For path mode I select copy and check the Embed texture Icon, I set the selection to (limited to, selected objects) and that's it, I hit export FBX
The FBX keeps the roughness but changes the metallic to a more gray version of the original, and changes base color and the normals to rgbs. The color is okay being a RBG but the normals take a whole other turn and are no longer normals when it's imported back into blender, it turns into a RGB and is ruined. Any ideas why this is happening. Also I'm just importing back into blender when this happens. And it's a .Blend file to begin with.

I never ask questions but this is a puzzleing one and I figured was worth asking